# Creating new dictionary from two different lists

Tags: python, dictionary, python-zip

I'm looking for a way to write this code in more elegant way

```
new_dict = {}
for i in range(len(j)):
    result_bool_list = j[i].get("A").get("B").get("C")
    or_result = all(result_bool_list)
    new_dict.update([(ListA[i], or_result )])
```

The code is creating a new dictionary in which K comes from listA and V is the OR calculation for all Boolean values in nested json (j) while

len(listA) == len(j)

Comment: Looping over `range(len(X))` is pointless if you only use the value for indexing into `X`.  Do `for element in X:`, and use `element` directly.  Also, using `.update()` to add a single entry to a dict is overly complicated - use `D[key] = value` instead.  (And maybe you have a good reason for this, but it might be better to store the boolean value directly in your dict, rather than the `str()` of that boolean.)

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper , regarding str() for Boolean value , you're right , I forgot to remove it before posting the code  - fixed 
If I'm switching to for element in X then I'm loosing index which is also an index for pulling the key from other array

Comment: solved by using 'enumerate'

Thank you